# ionic browser not work sqlite / ionic serve not work googlemaps... how to test?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working on my first new ionic application (using Ionic 4) and I'm facing some difficulties on how to test the app after installed GoogleMaps API.

Running `ionic serve -c`, the Google Maps API says: "ionic serve is not supported"

Running `ionic run browser`, I get `exec proxy not found for SQLitePlugin` and acoording to my searches, it doesn't work with browser.

So, what is the best way to work with Ionic and test it during development?

Comment: Run in android emulator

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test SQLite in the browser you must generate an app or run it via ADB on a emulator/device.
For Android you can do all of the work from the command line. Simply build your app like always, install it with ADB and once you want to get the databse you can use the ADB shell as well to extract it from your app to your local filesystem like this:

```
ionic cordova build android

# Install the APK with adb install

# Run the app through the shell and copy the DB file
adb -d shell "run-as io.ionic.starter cat databases/data.db" > ~/androiddb.db
```